# How to install regex for Python with pip?

Tags: centos, regular-expression, python, yum, pip

How do I install regex for python in CentOS?

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ pip3 install re
Collecting re
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement re (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for re
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
bcc (0.8.0)
blivet (3.1.0)
Brlapi (0.6.7)
cffi (1.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
chrome-gnome-shell (0.0.0)
configobj (5.0.6)
coverage (4.5.1)
cryptography (2.3)
cupshelpers (1.0)
dbus-python (1.2.4)
decorator (4.2.1)
gpg (1.10.0)
html5lib (0.999999999)
idna (2.5)
iniparse (0.4)
initial-setup (0.3.62.1)
iotop (0.6)
isc (2.0)
jsonpointer (1.10)
kmod (0.1)
langtable (0.0.38)
libvirt-python (4.5.0)
lxml (4.2.3)
netaddr (0.7.19)
netifaces (0.10.6)
ntplib (0.3.3)
ordered-set (2.0.2)
pciutils (2.3.6)
pcp (4.1)
perf (0.1)
pid (2.1.1)
pip (9.0.3)
ply (3.9)
productmd (1.11)
psycopg2 (2.7.5)
pwquality (1.4.0)
pycairo (1.16.3)
pycparser (2.14)
pycups (1.9.72)
pycurl (7.43.0.2)
pydbus (0.6.0)
pygobject (3.28.3)
pykickstart (3.16.7)
pyOpenSSL (18.0.0)
pyparted (3.11.0)
PySocks (1.6.8)
python-augeas (0.5.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
python-dmidecode (3.12.2)
python-linux-procfs (0.6)
python-meh (0.47.2)
pytz (2017.2)
pyudev (0.21.0)
pyxdg (0.25)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.20.0)
requests-file (1.4.3)
requests-ftp (0.3.1)
rhnlib (2.8.6)
rpm (4.14.2)
rtslib-fb (2.1.69)
schedutils (0.6)
selinux (2.9)
sepolicy (1.1)
setools (4.2.2)
setroubleshoot (1.1)
setuptools (39.2.0)
simpleline (1.1)
six (1.11.0)
slip (0.6.4)
slip.dbus (0.6.4)
sos (3.7)
SSSDConfig (2.2.0)
syspurpose (1.25.17)
systemd-python (234)
urllib3 (1.24.2)
webencodings (0.5.1)
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core) 
Release:    8.1.1911
Codename:   Core
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Comment: From what I can tell, module re is a normal part of standard python distribution since 1.6 (should be in python's Lib\re.py). I'm not familiar with CentOS, but if you run the command `python -c "import re ; help(re)"` does it print `ImportError: No module named re` or does it print the help page for module re?

Comment: `python3 -c "import re ; help(re)"` prints the help page -- so it's already there.